# Java @Override not working. Still executing Not Overridden Method

Tags: java, overriding

When I execute the following little Program the method onStart() doesn't get overridden and I get the Output "onStartSuper". I already looked for similar problems, but found nothing that worked.

Java Code:

```
public class main extends OSAATE {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        System.out.println("Start");
    }

}

public class OSAATE {

public static OSAATE osaate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        osaate = new OSAATE();

        osaate.onStart();
    }

    public void onStart() {

        System.out.println("onStartSuper");
    }

}
```

Comment: That's because `osaate` is not an instance of `main` but an instance of the superclass `OSAATE` - so of course the super method will be executed. Btw `@Override` doesn't have any runtime effect but is meant for the compiler, i.e. to help it warn you about potential errors like thinking a method without the annotation doesn't override a super method when it does or a method with the annotation doesn't actually override anything.

Comment: You never instantiate an instance of class `main`, so why would you expect the `onStart` method in `main` to be called?

Comment: What everyone here is trying to say is that you should have `osaate = new main()` if you expect the overridden function to run. You really should read [some tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) if you need to understand how inheritance works in java.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to run this from the other class instead of the same class the parent is?

```
 public class main extends OSSATE{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      osaate = new OSAATE();

      osaate.onStart();
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart() {

   System.out.println("Start");
}
}
```

Comment: I wanted to move "public static void main(String[] args)" into the other class. My aim is it to just extend OSAATE and use it like JFrame, etc...

Comment: Ok so fore you to override something it needs to be a child class. I would suggest that you move the main into an other class and execute.